# Nvme not recognized after Windows 11 update

Tags: bios, windows-11, nvme

I have been facing a problem since I upgraded from Win 10 to Win 11. In fact, Windows no longer recognizes my two nvme SSDs (Samsung 970 evo plus), neither in the disk manager nor in the storage manager. peripherals but they are recognized in the bios. The bios seems correctly configured (AHCI and UEFI). (Windows is intall in an other ssd SATA).

I tried updating the bios with the latest version but it didn't change anything. All the forums talk about doing actions either on the disk manager or on the device manager, but my disks no longer appear anywhere (except in the bios) since this damn Windows 11 update... I just want my disks to be operational again. It doesn't matter if I lose my data.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Unless something went wrong with your base Windows (appears so), Windows 11 updates do not damage drives.  If no recognition of drives, you may need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Are they seen by some Live Linux or Live Windows (e.g. Hiren Boot DVD) live OSs? Just create a bootable Live Linux pen drive, boot off it and check. Make sure that in Win 11 Control Panel - Device Manager the default NVM Express controller is enabled. It will be under section or drop down called Storage Controller.